# <<Spring Boot 1.1.6>> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and building an application with Spring boot 1.1.6.The basic application was working fine.

But when I added some dependencies, I am unable to start the application and seeing the below exception during staring.

My build.gradle file

```
` buildscript {
    ext {

        springBootVersion = '1.1.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { 
        url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" 
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

war {
    baseName = 'gs-convert-jar-to-war'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        exclude module:"spring-boot-starter-logging"
    }
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBootVersion}")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}")

    compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
    compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")
    compile("com.local.abdd:abdd-jith912:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"){
    exclude module:"slf4j-api"
    }
    compile("com.local.abdd:abdd-jith912:1.0.4-SNAPSHOT:tests"){
    exclude module:"slf4j-api"
    }
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7"){
    force = true
    }
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7"){
    force=true
    }
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.7"){
    force=true
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
`
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: ; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.Application.main(Application.java:27)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:561)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:389)
    ... 13 more
```

My gradle dependencies output is too huge that I cannot enter here.
However I find some spring components used as transitive dependencies like

```
  |    +--- com.local.infra.thirdparty:oracle-simplefan:11.2.0.2
|    |         |    |    |    |    +--- javax.jms:jms:1.1
|    |         |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.1.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.1.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.1.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.1.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.1.RELEASE -> 3.2.2.RELEASE
|    |         |    |    |    |    |         +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |         |    |    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |         |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.2.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
```

and

```
 +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.0.4.RELEASE -> 3.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.0.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.0.4.RELEASE -> 3.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.0.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.0.4.RELEASE -> 3.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.0.3.RELEASE -> 3.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.3.RELEASE -> 4.0.7.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    |    |         |    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.0.4.RELEASE -> 3.2.5.RELEASE (*)
```

Comment: Yuo haven't added all dependencies. It is strongly recommended to use the Spring Boot starter projects when adding parts or at least use the Spring bOot provided dependency versions. Please add your pom.

Comment: Hi Deinum, Thanks for the helping hand.I am using the build.gradle file from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/blob/master/initial/build.gradle with additional entries referring to my local repository.

Comment: Please don't add files as comments, edit and extend your initial question.

Comment: As stated please add your gradle file. Pointing to the original one without knowing what you changed will not work.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `gradle dependencies`, please?

Comment: Hi Andy Wilkinson, I have updated the question with the partial dependency tree ,as the full tree is huge.Do you think these transitive dependencies can have an impact on the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this will solve your problem, but it will move things in the right direction.

You have a number of dependencies that are out of sync with other dependencies from the same Spring project. For example you have a mix of versions in your Spring Framework dependencies. Most are 4.0.7.RELEASE but a few are 3.x.x.

One way to fix this is to add an explicit, direct dependency on the problematic modules (Spring Boot will provide the right version for you. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-security-acl'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-security-taglibs'
}
```

Try making this change and looking at the output of `gradle dependencies` again. Repeat the process if you spot any other modules with versions that are out of line with their other modules in the same Spring project. Once the versions all look right, try running your app again.

Comment: Gr8! specifying the dependency explicitly did the magic.Thanks Andy Wilkinson and Deinum.